# Trying to get props from map() ES6 and pass to other component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working with react ES6 and are having real trouble with trying to get the correct json objects out through products.map(). I've tried a lot of different things, however I end up the same place as i started.

I need to get price, title, color and url passed to the  component so i can use them as regular props-objects, however everything i tried failed so far.

I tried using the recommended function from react to pass the objects (return()), however, i need to iterate through PRODUCTS and assign a title, price, color and url to each instance of .

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
let PRODUCTS = [
{id: 1, price: '$49.99', title: 'Short blue dress', color: 'blue', url:'abc.com'},
{id: 2,price: '$9.99', title: 'Green long dress sleeveless', color: 'blue', url:'abc.com'},
{id: 3,price: '$29.99', title: 'Blue girl dress', color: 'green', url:'abc.com'},
{id: 4,price: '$99.99', title: 'Dress me dirty', color: 'green', url:'abc.com'},
{id: 5,price: '$399.99', title: 'Shirt with short sleeves', color: 'yellow', url:'abc.com'},
{id: 6,price: '$199.99', title: 'Something Something', color: 'yellow', url:'abc.com'}];

class SearchContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        location: PropTypes.object,
        products: PropTypes.object
}

constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
        open: false,
    };
}

handleDialog = (status) => {
    console.log(status);
    this.setState({ open: status });
}

render () {
var products = PRODUCTS
return (
    <div className='col-md-12' style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <div className='row searchPageHeader' style={{ padding: '10px', backgroundColor: '#1ABC9C' }}/>
            <Footer />
            <SideMenu />
            <SearchHeader query={this.props.location.query} />
        <div className='row' style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <div className='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
                {products.map((id, index) =>

          <div className='col-md-3' style={{ paddingBottom: '100px' }}>
              {console.log(products.id)}
              <CircleButton toggleDialog={this.handleDialog} query={this.props.location.query} products={this.props.product} />
          </div>
        )
      }
      </div>
      </div>
         {this.state.open && <Dialog closeOnOverlay={this.handleDialog} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean  `{products.map((products, index) => ...` and `console.log(product.id)` and passing `product` do `CircleButton`? It's really hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get price, title, color and url passed to my <CircleButton> component. My {console.log(products.id)} just gives me an "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you really want is this:

```
<div className='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
    {products.map(product => (
         <div key={product.id} className='col-md-3' style={{ paddingBottom: '100px' }}>
              {console.log(product.id)}
              <CircleButton
                   toggleDialog={this.handleDialog}
                   query={this.props.location.query}
                   products={product}
              />
         </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

or, simplified:

```
render() {

    const renderProduct = product => (
        <div key={product.id} className='col-md-3' style={{ paddingBottom: '100px' }}>
             {console.log(product.id)}
             <CircleButton
                 toggleDialog={this.handleDialog}
                 query={this.props.location.query}
                 products={product}
             />
        </div>
    );

    ...
```

and then

```
<div className='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
    {products.map(renderProduct)}
</div>
```

Highlights:

1. the first parameter in the `map` function is a `product`. Not an `id`.
2. you were not using the parameters of the `map` function at all
3. you need a `key` to identify generated components in `map`.
4. you were passing `this.props.products` to the subcomponents, which is something completely different.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, a huge thank you! However, how do I call these props in my CircleButton? I have products: PropTypes.object set up and are trying to use {console.log(props.price)}

EDIT: I got it, i forgot the props.product.price! Thank you!